# different theme in one website

Tags: database, wordpress, themes

Assume this is my site name : `www.example.com.`

I saw different websites have different themes in a site. For example I want to have different themes for `www.example.com` and `www.example.com/othertheme.` I know it should have different database for that. But how?

Comment: Should the content be shared between the two themes, or are you just asking how to run multiple Wordpress installations on one domain?

Comment: @Blender different theme different data different post ......

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_Multiple_Blogs

Comment: @Blender I told I know that I should have 2 databases. but what should I do after that?

Comment: You don't *need* to have multiple databases. Just read through that guide and follow the instructions. When you install Wordpress, I think it asks you something about a database prefix. Instead of choosing `wp_`, use something like `wp_blog1_`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should make a directory to the root of the server which named for example othertheme which has another database. then I can go to that website with this url : www.example.com/othertheme. So it has different theme in one website.